# Automating Config Files creation in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cicd

I am trying to automate the creation of a Custom file (one of the Config File types in the Config File Provider plugin) in Jenkins. Checking the official API documentation (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/) I can only see a few features of it. It says that you can access to more information for a specific feature ending the URL with ".../api". I have tried to access to "https://www.mylocaljenkinsinstance.com/manage/configfiles/api" but it returns a 404 error:

[image]

Do you know how can I automate the creation of Config Files from outside Jenkins?